# jquery window opener doesn'nt work

Tags: jquery, input, window, window.opener

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function PreviewContent(lang) {
    window.open("<?php echo base_url('system/pages/preview/about/') ?>" + lang, "ckeditor_preview", "location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,width=980,height=600");
}

</script>

<tr>                                            
<td valign="top"><?php echo lang('label_content'); ?></td><td>
                                             <?php                                              echo $this->ckeditor->editor("content[$lang_k]", $text->content);                   ?>                                          
<input type="button" value="Preview Content" onclick="PreviewContent('/<?php echo $lang_k;    ?>');" /></td>
```

and the opener window script is

```
<script>
$().ready(function() {
$('.preview_content').html(window.opener.jQuery("input[name=content]<?php echo $p_lang; ?>").value);
});    
</script>

<div class="preview_content"></div>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: what do you expect?  what actually happens?  i don't see an input named `content` anywhere and i don't know why you're injecting from PHP directly into a jQuery selector string.

Answer (score 0):

Corrections.

- `$(document).ready`
- `input[name="content"]`
- `content['".$lang_k.".]`

  `$('.preview_content').html(window.opener.jQuery("input[name="content"]<?php echo $p_lang; ?>").value);`

`.html()` is used to set HTML inside of selected element.